# ¿Cómo arreglar esta excepción?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Estoy tratando de aprender a trabajar con `OsmSharp` y que sea offline, entonces cuando creo un proyecto de Android con Xamarin. En la línea:

```
map.AddLayer(new LayerScene(Scene2D.Deserialize(sceneStream, true)));
```

Me da la excepción:

> Your app has entered a break state but there is no code to show
>   because all threads were executing external code.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    // hide title bar.
    this.RequestWindowFeature(global::Android.Views.WindowFeatures.NoTitle);

    // initialize map.
    var map = new Map();

    var sceneStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("App1.default.map");
    map.AddLayer(new LayerScene(Scene2D.Deserialize(sceneStream, true)));

    // define the mapview.
    var mapViewSurface = new MapViewSurface(this);
    _mapView = new MapView(this, mapViewSurface);
    _mapView.Map = map;
    _mapView.MapMaxZoomLevel = 17; // limit min/max zoom because MBTiles sample only contains a small portion of a map.
    _mapView.MapMinZoomLevel = 12;
    _mapView.MapTilt = 0;
    _mapView.MapCenter = new GeoCoordinate(51.26361, 4.78620);
    _mapView.MapZoom = 16;
    _mapView.MapAllowTilt = false;

    // set the map view as the default content view.
    SetContentView(_mapView);
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio @Wilber. Por favor edita la pregunta e indica más detalles del error: mensaje, stacktrace, etc.

Comment: @Wiber, por favor no publiques duplicados de tus preguntas. Publica solo una pregunta. Si necesitas agregar información, puedes editar la pregunta mediante la opción que se encuentra al pie del cuerpo.

Comment: @Wilber-concepcion-lugo podrias agregar el stacktrace?

Comment: Este error más que de la aplicación se refiere a Visual Studio, te recomiendo darle un `Clean` a la solución y luego dale `Rebuild` para volverla a probar

Comment: Prueba partirlo en tres lineas a ver en cual da el error:
var scene2d=Scene2D.Deserialize(sceneStream, true);
var layer_scene=new LayerScene(scene2d);
map.AddLayer(layer_scene);

Answer (score 1):

En realidad esa no es la excepción debes revisar en la consola de salida cual es el problema, para eso debes continuar la ejecución de tu aplicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y posteriormente se desplegará el problema verdadero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]